# Node.js Error Handling

Tags: node.js

I have the following code to insert data into DB - this code has to be executed in a sequential order

Router JS

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/registerUser', function(req, res ) {

            objuser.userName  = 'testuser';
            objuser.password  = 'password';

            objuser.status  = true;

            registerUser (objuser ); //calls Business.js
            res.OK();
            res.end ();
    });
}
```

Business.js

```
var registerUser =  function (objuser  )
{


  userDB.registerUser (objuser ) ; //calls db.js

};
```

db.js

```
exports.registerUser  = function (objUser )
{

        var User = db.model(strCollectionName, UserSchema );

        var objSchema = new User(objUser);
        objSchema.save(function (err)
        {
            if (err)
               console.error (err);
            else
                console.log ("registerUser : Data insertion success.");

        });

}
```

In the db.js Im getting error from Mongo if I try to insert duplicate value. I wan to pass the error message to HTML page to display the same. What should I do? I tried

throw Error (err)

But it breaks the server.

Comment: You should use callbacks and reply to HTTP request only when insertion is done (or errored).

Comment: You should pass res (and optionally req for consistency) to where you actually make a DB operation and then respond accordingly. Or use closure. Basically, the point is to have access to res, so you can respond to HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using expressjs, I'd make use of the `next` callback.  like so:

```
app.get('/registerUser', function (req, res, next) {
    objuser.userName  = 'testuser';
    objuser.password  = 'password';

    objuser.status  = true;

    registerUser(objuser, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            //this will be handled by express's errorHandler or whatever you have configured
            return next(err); 
        }
        //do whatever you want to do with the response
    });
});
```

If you don't want to make your Business.js call async then you will obviously change this code to a `try...catch` flow. Node.js apps are happier using async calls though, so a common convention in nodejs apps is to expose a callback using the `(err, result)` parameters. So your `db.js` call would be :

```
exports.registerUser  = function (objUser, callback )
{    
        var User = db.model(strCollectionName, UserSchema );
        var objSchema = new User(objUser);
        objSchema.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            return callback(null, objSchema);

        });
}
```

By now you probably notice that your `Business.js` call would just be a mediator between your route and your db code...whether you need it or not is up to you.

HTH,
Mike

Comment: Thanks !! One thing that I want to ask is, How to send the error message to HTML page to display the error message and error code (something like 500, 401 etc)?

Comment: This doc [here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) is pretty good. The thing to remember with express routing is the order in which you setup your routes...;ie, don't forget to configure your error handling fn until after the app.router is setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js >= 0.8.x you can use [connect-domain](https://github.com/baryshev/connect-domain) middleware that adds [new domain functionality](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) to your express/connect application. With doamin module you don't need to pass error up manually. You can simple throw error and it will be passed to error handler automatically.